# Canonical Partition Function - Why does the probability for a system to be in a state not take into consideration the Helmholtz exponential component?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, partition-function

It is known that the equation to calculate the probability for a system to be in a specific energy level is

$\sum_s{P_s}
 = 1 = e^{\beta F} \sum_s e^{-\beta E_s}$,

where the sum component is now considered to be the canonical partition function ,$Z$.

However, when we're computing the probability of finding the system in a specific energy level, we only use each individual $Z$ values, without introducing the $e^{\beta F}$ component,

i.e. $P_0 = \frac{Z_0}{Z_{total}}$, $P_1 = \frac{Z_1}{Z_{total}}..$ . Why is this?